# Access the a built-in camera from Safari installed on an iPhone, iPad, or iPod Touch?

Tags: iphone, ipad, webcam, ipod-touch

Is there a genuine way to access the a built-in camera from Safari intalled on an iPhone, iPad,  or iPod Touch?

By genuine I mean no hack, no workaround, no extra app to install.

There is no flash capability installed on the web browser for those devices and I need to enable my users to, with their permission, be able to use the camera as a web cam for a chatting site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this.  You need to use an API that allows you to access the camera, and those are only available for native applications, not a web application.